# Reading data from QVD using python and databricks

Tags: qliksense

I am new to python,can you help me with the details of how QVD can be read into azure databricks dataframe using python.

I need the detail syntax (authentication with access key)of accessing the QVD from datalake and the read the same using qvd_reader